# Google Signin API Integration works on Localhost but not on production Error 403

Tags: php, google-api, google-signin, http-status-code-403, google-api-php-client

I implemented Google SignIn API in my website, It works fine on LocalHost, but when i uploaded it on the Live Server, It gives Error 403 "Forbidden" after the user enter credentials and the google redirects the user to my website. I tried following different articles online, but no luck so far. Note: My Google App is already verified by Google.
Please can anyone help me understand the problem?
Thanks.

[403 Forbidden Error! Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hqJU.jpg)

[Redirect Error on Live Server but works fine on LocalHost, screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxZO5.jpg)

Comment: Seems like a server configuration rather than a Google SignIn problem